# Show first and last name in header when using Gmail API (python)

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I have my mail `my_name@company.com` and uses gmails API (and python) to send some mails. The problem is that when the mail hit the inbox the "from" is shown as `my_name@company.com '<my_name@company.com>'` where I want it to be `First Name <my_name@company.com>`.

I have tried using different variations of `"First Name '<my_name@company.com>'"` but I get a `RefreshError: ('invalid_request: Invalid impersonation &quot;sub&quot; field.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_request",\n  "error_description": "Invalid impersonation \\u0026quot;sub\\u0026quot; field."\n}')`.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient import errors
from httplib2 import Http
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Email variables. Modify this!
EMAIL_FROM = "First Last '<my_name@company.com>'"
EMAIL_TO = 'some_mail@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Hello  from Me!'
EMAIL_CONTENT = 'Some body'


# Call the Gmail API

def service_account_login():
  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
  SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'my-credentials.json'

  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
          SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
  delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(EMAIL_FROM)
  service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)
  return service


def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):

  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  raw = raw.decode()
  return {"raw": raw}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):

  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except errors.HttpError as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)

service = service_account_login()
message = create_message(EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_TO, EMAIL_SUBJECT, EMAIL_CONTENT)
sent = send_message(service,'me', message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just sent an email recently showing the name as you wanted, I got it with this line, similar to what you already had but without the single quotation marks:

```
message['from'] = "First Name <something@example.com>"
```

Answer (score 0):

So the trick is fairly simple - the `EMAIL_FROM` is first used to create a service with that email, which is why you cannot write `My Name <my_name@company.com>`. You can do that when you need to specify the "FROM " mail e.g in the very buttom of `create_message= f"First name<{EMAIL_FROM}>,...)`